# How do you block the whole file location from accessing the internet? WINDOWS 8

Tags: windows, internet, blocking, spotify, file-location

Windows 8 ~ Ok well i just want to know how to block Spotify (and everything it is related to) from internet access (What ever i do i cant seem to find the actual file that connects to the internet, that then transfers it to "Spotify.exe")

Well the first comment didnt help what so ever (as i was already using windows firewall) and i dont know where to block the specific location. (Hence why im asking)

All I want to do is block everything in "C:\Users-USER HERE-\AppData\Roaming\Spotify" So nothing can assess the internet. I have blocked every .EXE in the file path individually so there has to be a file that calls the internet packets and transfers it to Spotify.exe (So techincally speaking spotify.exe isn't connected to the internet even though it is still sending and receiving internet packets, So blocking it in Win Firewall does nothing).

Comment: You can use Windows Firewall to do this

Comment: Kady, could you please clarify? What do you mean by finding the "actual file that connects to the internet"?

Comment: Well the first comment didnt help what so ever (as i was already using windows firewall) and i dont know where to block the specific location. (Hence why im asking)

...........................

All I want to do is block everything in "C:\Users\-USER HERE-\AppData\Roaming\Spotify" So nothing can assess the internet. I have blocked every .EXE in the file path individually so there has to be a file that calls the internet packets and transfers it to Spotify.exe (So techincally speaking spotify.exe isn't connected to the internet even though it is still sending and receiving internet packets).

Comment: No need to repeat in comments what you already stated in the question. What problem are you actually trying to solve?  Not just blocking spotify but why?  there may well be a better mousetrap if you tell the whole story.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly it would be better if you tell us why you want to block it in the first place, there should be a better solution to this. Also Spotify(Free) requires internet access to work (unless local files are played, but then why not use Media Player?) so not sure why you want to do this...

What antivirus are you using? Some antivirus software have firewalls which replace Windows Firewall.

For example, I use AVG, and in its firewall I can set it to block Spotify like this:
[image]

After blocking it and starting Spotify the blocking works because it can't connect to the internet.

This should be possible with **Windows Firewall** with **Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall**.